# Why is $P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A)}{P(B)} \frac{P( A \cap B)}{P(A)}$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I do not understand the green part of this deriviation in a book about probability theory $\color{blue}{(1)}$:
$$ P(A \mid B) = \color{green}{\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A)}{P(B)} \frac{P( A \cap B)}{P(A)}} = \frac{P(A)}{P(B)}P(B \mid A)$$

To me it looks like if we substituted these probabilities with normal numbers we could assign it randomly like this:
$$
P(A \cap B) = 5, P(B) = 7, P(A) = 10)
$$
And get$\color{blue}{(2)}$:

$$
 \frac{5}{7} = \frac{10}{7} \frac{5}{10}
$$

Which is true and I can tell that it gives us the so called backwards conditional probability as a final result.

My teacher calls this the conditional probability "reversal" formula, but this is actually what is know as Bayes Theorem. Other people just write it as$\color{blue}{(3)}$:
$$
P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(B \mid A)P(A)}{P(B)}
$$

- Is it correct that this is actually Bayes Theorem that he is trying to derive just without using the name for it in $\color{blue}{(1)}$ ?
- What is the best way to explain my back of the envelope deductions in $\color{blue}{(2)} $ ? Because I guess it is just some algebra trick being used here but I would really appreciate if anyone could put mathematical terms on what is going on exactly.

EDIT:
Yeah okay, I understand my confusion now. So they use a trick, they multiply with $\frac{P(A)}{P(A)}$
So they get:
$$\frac{P(A)}{P(A)}\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} 
$$
This is equivalent to:
$$ P(A)\frac{1}{P(A)} P(A \cap B)\frac{1}{P(B)}  
$$
And because multiplication is commutative we can just assemble it differently:
$$\frac{P(A)}{P(B)}\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} 
$$

Comment: They've multiplied by $1$ in a fancy way: by multiplying and dividing by $P(A)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition :
$$p(A | B) = \dfrac{p(A \cap B)}{p(B)} \text{ and } p(B | A) = \dfrac{p(A \cap B)}{p(A)}$$
then :
$$p(A | B) p(B) = p(A \cap B) = p(B | A) p(A)$$
And Finally :
$$p(A | B) = \dfrac{p(A)}{p(B)} p(B | A)$$

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the green formula is just the definition of conditional probability: $P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$. The second part of the green formula is the result of multiplying $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ by $1 = \frac{P(A)}{P(A)}$.

You can't assign probabilities "randomly" in the way that you suggest. Probabilities must be between $0$ and $1$. You can't have a probability of $5$.

Comment: Okay, If I multiply the two then I have $  \frac{P(A)P(A \cap B) }{P(A)P(B)}$ right? how does that get me closer?

Comment: Never mind, I get it now. thanks for the help.